# Is it possible to add a cpt that can only be viewed in backend, not edited?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to log user requests (from frontend) to the database.

Is this possible and does it make sense to do this with a CPT?

The admin should be able to view the requests, but not to edit them.

Comment: It certainly is, though one way of doing it will involve having your own UI. There's nothing to prevent you having a post type or taxonomy that is hidden in the admin area, and building your own interface. You might want to look into adjusting roles and capabilities when registering your post type, but there isn't a read only view by default in the admin area

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation for `register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), I'd suggest trying to set `show_ui` to `false` in the array of arguments you're passing in:

> **'show_ui'**
>   *(bool)* Whether to generate and allow a UI for managing this post type in the admin. Default is value of `$public`.

Depending on your scenario, you might be better off setting `public` to `false`.